# How do I get back my Nautilus folder browser?

Tags: nautilus

The Nautilus that I get on pressing Super-E is now missing the left-hand folder-browse panel. All I have is the right-hand  panel listing files and folders inside a given folder.

How do I get back  the left-hand panel?

(Ubuntu 18.04.1)

[image: Nautilus]

Comment: Can you try pressing f9

Comment: Yes! Please write this as an  answer so I can accept it.